# Unable to take a screenshot

Tags: android

I can't make a screenshot on my mobile Samsung Galaxy A8. Please help me to figure this out because as far as I know I didn't change any security settings on my phone

Comment: this question has nothing to do with programming

Comment: Its not place for this type of questions . You can use [stackexchange.com](https://stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Do you want take screenshot programatically?

Answer (score 0):

Try pressing volume down and home key together, it should work!